Phantom wallet swap failure
For example, let's assume I purchase a token, put $30 into it, and it increases to $40. I try to swap it, and generally it works, but sometimes it just fails to swap, then the token crashes and I lose most of the $30 I had invested in addition to the $10 gain. It has twice taken place. It failed for hours yesterday, and for the past half hour or so, it is still failing. I find it incredibly hard to understand this. How come there is so much congestion in Solana while people are clearly continuing trading and acting normally even after this has been going on for hours? What makes their actions different? Is it just phantom?

Try swapping on Jupiter (jup.ag), the Phantom swap feature isn't very reliable in my experience. You can also increase your slippage for more success.
